# How to know that the list items are added successfully in QML listview?

Tags: qt, qml

I have created a list of buttons using delegate.

```
ListView
 {
   id: list
   width: 180; height: 200
   delegate: Button
     {
         width: 180; height: 40
         //assigning few properties
     }
}
```

From my .cpp I clear the list and again adding items.
Is there any signal that I can check every time the list is refreshed, and all items are added successfully?

Comment: You add the items to the `ListView` directly? How and why?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a proper `QAbstractListModel`, it includes notification for adding and removing list items. So changes will be reflected automatically and in the most efficient manner.

Sounds like you are using a plain `QList` exposed as a model, that's pretty much wrong, especially when you have a dynamic and changing model. You can still force update by exposing the list as a `Q_PROPERTY` with a `NOTIFY` signal, but that will be wildly inefficient, as it will cause all delegates to be recreated for every change, rather than efficiently reflecting changes only.

Answer (score -1):

you can add handler to your button

```
Component.onCompleted: console.log("button is created")
```

to make sure that button is being constructed

Comment: A `ListView` is supposed to create and destroy the objects as needed (within view), so - if it is done with any kind of model - you can't be sure to have the `Item`s created, as they might be outside the displayed range.